# How to solve lighttpd "No input file specified."

Tags: webserver, lighttpd, php-5.5

Last time I was using Apache2+PHP5 as my web server and it run normally unless too slow when server is process my script and I had change it to lighttpd + fastcgi. It faster than and low memory usage.

My problem is when lighttpd running some time it "No input file specified." but some time is ok. But when I restart lighttpd every come to normally.
I don't know why and how to solve it.

This is my config.

```
$SERVER["socket"] == ":80" {

$HTTP["host"] == "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" {
    server.document-root = "/var/www/public_html"
    server.errorlog = "/var/www/public_html/logs/error.log"
    accesslog.filename = "/var/www/public_html/logs/access.log"
    compress.cache-dir = "/var/www/public_html/cache"
}

$HTTP["host"] == "sub.domain.com" {
    server.document-root = "/var/www/public_html"
    server.errorlog = "/var/www/public_html/logs/error.log"
    accesslog.filename = "/var/www/public_html/logs/access.log",
    compress.cache-dir = "/var/www/public_html/cache"
}
index-file.names   = ( "index.php", "index.html", "index.htm", "default.htm" )
url.rewrite-if-not-file = (
         "^/image(.*)" => "/image-api.php$1",
         "^/go/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)" => "/index.php?go=$1",
         "^/oembed(.*)" => "/oembed_provider/index.php$1",
         "^/player$" => "/library/plugin/video-player/player.swf",
         "^/v(.*)" => "/cvd.php$1",
         "^/me" => "/user.php",
         "^/@(.*)\?(.*)" => "/profile.php?indentity=$1&$2",
         "^/@(.*)" => "/profile.php?indentity=$1",
         "^/url?g=(.*)" => "/url.php?g=$1",
         "^/social_auth/(.*)" => "/partner_api/$1.php",
         "^/c/(.*)" => "/view.php?view=$1",
         "^/u/(.*)" => "/profile.php?indentity=$1",
         "^/project/(.*)" => "/section.php?page=$1",
         "^/min/(.*)" => "/mini/index.php$1",
         "^/src/(.*)" => "/src/$1",
         "^/library/(.*)" => "/library/$1",
         "^/\?(.*)" => "/index.php?$1",
         "^/(.*)\?(.*)" => "/page.php?p=$1&$2",
         "^/(.*)" => "/page.php?p=$1"
        )

$HTTP["host"] == "domain.org" {
url.redirect = ("/(.*)$" => "https://domain.com/$1")
}

$HTTP["host"] == "domain.info" {
url.redirect = ("/(.*)$" => "https://domain.com/$1")
}

$HTTP["host"] == "domain.net" {
url.redirect = ("/(.*)$" => "https://domain.com/$1")
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [FAQ](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/frequentlyaskedquestions), it looks like there are several possibilities:

> **I get the error "No input file specified" when trying to use PHP**
>
> Sadly, this error message can mean a lot of things.
> A common explanation attempt: PHP is unable to locate or open the file which it
> is supposed to parse.
>
> This can have a lot of reasons:
>
> - You forgot to
>   add ''cgi.fix_pathinfo=1 to your php.ini'' file. See the comments in
>   the [PHP docs](http://www.php.net/manual/de/security.cgi-bin.php). The issue here is that the environment variable
>   SCRIPT_FILENAME is not being passed to PHP.
> - Make sure you did not set
>   **doc_root or userdir in php.ini**, or if you have set it, make sure it
>   has the correct value (doc_root should match lighttpd's
>   server.document-root option in this case)
> - If open_basedir is set, make
>   sure the requested file is below one of the directories which is
>   specified there. In the past PHP parsed files which were not inside
>   open_basedir as well, but this security problem was fixed (in
>   php-5.2.3 or so).
> - If you are running PHP with different permissions
>   than lighttpd (spawn-fcgi with -u/-g, execwrap, suexec, ...), check
>   that PHP can really read the file
>
> If you are unable to find / fix the
> problem, you can use strace to see if it is a (OS-related) permission
> problem (look out for stat*(...YOURFILE...) = RETURNCODE). It might
> help to set max-procs to 1 and PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN as well (see fastcgi
> docs) in that case, so that you can easily attach strace to the
> correct php-cgi process.